# Strange things happen when I use passport for user authentication in Nodejs+Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

In the beginning, I used this code to define LocalStrategy

```
    passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField:'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqtoCallback: true
        },
            function(req,username,password,done){
            ....
```

Then, the passport couldn't work well.It read password as username and couldn't read username from the HTML form.

I was so confused and then I downloaded other people's source code and applied it to my code.
In fact, I only changed above part to this:

```
 passport.use(
  'local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField: 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
 function(req,username,password,done){
            ....
```

And it just worked!!!!

Actually, I  think those two codes are only different in indentation.So what is my original mistake?Could anyone tell me, thanks!

(To make it more clear , I upload the screenshot from my IDE)

This is buggy Code.
[image: This is Buggy Code]

This is the code that works well.
[image: Good Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you have

```
passport.use(
  'local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
    ...
    passReqtoCallback: true // misspelled!
  }),
  ...
)
```

instead of

```
passport.use(
  'local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
    ...
    passReqToCallback: true
  }),
  ...
)
```